# Ping federate, Federation hub vs Target sessions

Tags: authentication, pingfederate

I have 2 target applications that I need to get authenticated with the same authentication service (And then able to being logged out), My server is acting as a SP and IDP. So As far as I understand I need to map in some way an idp adapter with 2 sp adapters.  I was able to create correctly the idp adapter and the sp adapters for my scenario. And also I can create the idp connection and the sp connections, but I am not sure which is the correct path to follow.

- I can create 1 idp connection and 1 sp connection that will have 2 Target sessions: like explained here: https://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/PF73/Configuring+Target+Session+Mapping, and then map this target urls like explaned here: https://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/PF73/Configuring+Target+URL+Mapping#ConfiguringTargetURLMapping-3235154
- I can create 1 idp connection and 2 sp connections and configure something called a "federation hub" like explained here: https://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/PF73/Bridging+an+IdP+to+multiple+SPs

Which should be the correct and easy path for my use case?

Comment: Are you actually on 7.3? The options available with regards to adapters and sessions in 8.4 (current release as of this post) are much more mature.

Comment: I see, I am actually on pingfederate 8.3.13, so I moved my configuration to use adapter to adapters, looks much easier to understand than connections !